# Why is render glyph so slow?

Tags: render, framebuffer, freetype, freetype2

I use linux framebuffer draw chinese by freetype2, and compare the fbterm

```
Font::Glyph *Font::getGlyph(u32 unicode)
void Screen::draw##bits(u32 x, u32 y, u32 w, u8 fc, u8 bc, u8 *pixmap)
```

and remove cache glyph part.

```
    if (glyphCache[unicode]) return glyphCache[unicode];
```

But my program render chinese is so slow.

My code is the same the fbterm almost (render glyph part).

I only know, if I skip the  `FT_Load_Glyph(face, index, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT);` part,
I can render so fast, but I guess that this is not key point.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is different font type.
If I use unifont.pcf.gz, get glyph needs more time.
If I use bsmi00lp.ttf,,get glyph needs less time, and render glyph very fast.